# How does a proxy(like squid) knows if the connection is using http?

Tags: http, proxy

I'm thinking of make my own protocol tunneling with http.
So, in some cases we have user and password for proxies like squid.

1-How does it know is really http going on?? does it checks the contents of the TCP connection on port 80??
2-If so then I really need to use http. If dont I can use any TCP connection on port 80?

Comment: It must be HTTP, as a proxy must know what is being fetched (e.g. for caching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It checks the content decoding and interpreting the HTTP requests and responses, otherwise the proxy wouldn't know where to forward the request.

HTTPS is a different thing (proxy can't read encrypted ssl connections) and just interprets a single CONNECT line sent before the HTTPS traffic.

More Information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel